# Logged in sessions in Blazor ServerSide App

Tags: php, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am new to Blazor and I am creating a prototype website for a project. I am aware of the Blazor Authentication/Authorisation function but I don't want to use this. Is there an easier way to store the logged in users id such as the way you can store this with PHP start/end sessions for logged in users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser local storage or session storage to store user id. [ProtectedBrowserStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1#protected-browser-storage-experimental-package) library may help you